# discord.js pokemon filter cmd with array

Tags: arrays, discord.js

Hi I have a code which i am confused in how to do it.
I have a args string converted to array. Its like this
`["--name", "Shiny", "greninja", "--iv", "50"]`
I don't know how to take the shiny greninja part and not take the --iv 50 and not take shiny greninja one when i am taking the iv. Please help.

code: https://hastebin.com/tefiqesufu.js
error: No error it doesn't work the way i want i don't know how to

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific, you should give a sample of your code for people to see (in code shortner) otherwise no one will help. They don't know what you are talking about. Thank you!

Seif Sameh,
Freelancer